# PHP Array numbers

Tags: php, arrays

Easy question, I filled my array the following way:

```
$options = range(1, 10);
```

This will result:

```
  array
  (
     [0] => 1
     [1] => 2
     etc. etc.
  )
```

This is not the result I want..

I need my array like this:

```
 array
 (
   [1] => 1
   [2] => 2
   etc.
 )
```

How to accomplish this easy task?

Comment: not that i want to say you shouldn't, but please be aware that in computer science we start counting with 0, not with 1. So if you have an array starting with index 1, you have an array which is "missing" the first index. So only move up the array indices if you have a valid reason to!

Comment: My valid reason is as follow:
Selectbox with value 1, option 1 and so on.

Comment: @Jordy just add 1 while displaying it ;)

Comment: Well I'll fill my selectbox with CakePHP so it's a bit different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++ ) {
   $array[$i] = $i;
}
```

Voila. :)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe like this:

```
$options = range(0, 10);
unset($options[0]);
```

[working example](http://codepad.org/EgQG8f2D)

Comment: that won't give the expected result, the array would start with value `2` (for key `1`).

Comment: argh, sorry, my fault - didn't notice you started the range at `0`... +1 for you and shame on me.

Answer (score 2):

if you want a one-liner instead of a for-loop like Berry suggested, just use [array_combine](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$array = array_combine(range(1,10),range(1,10));
```

Comment: You are also a badass. Thanks!

Comment: yeah ... for vs 3 function calls!

Answer (score 2):

```
function myRange($start, $limit, $step)
{
    $myArr = array();
    foreach((array) range($start, $limit,$step) as $k => $v)
    {
        $myArr[$k+1] = $v;
    }
    return $myArr;
}

print_r(myRange(0, 100, 10));
?>
```

Result
    ------

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 20
    [4] => 30
    [5] => 40
    [6] => 50
    [7] => 60
    [8] => 70
    [9] => 80
    [10] => 90
    [11] => 100
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just shift the array

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $val )
    $result[ $key+1 ] = $val;
```